# Retag request: rdp->remote desktop

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

I see a lot of questions which are tagged both [rdp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rdp) and [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop). I have yet to see any where the question refers to the remote desktop *protocol* specifically; in every case, just [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop) should suffice. I propose that `rdp` be retagged to `remote-desktop` and set up as a synonym.

Comment: +1 I agree, acronyms that might not be well-known aren't useful. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going through [rdp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rdp) I spotted ~ 17 questions also tagged with [mstsc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mstsc).

Since mstsc is the application which implements rdp, I have gone ahead and added it as a  synonym for [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop)

To summarize:

[rdp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rdp) ࢐→ [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop)

[mstsc](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mstsc)→ [remote-desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/remote-desktop)

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Thanks, @Sathya!